# Best way to enable an user account to run supervisorctl?

Tags: ubuntu, supervisord

I've just finished setting up [supervisor](http://supervisord.org) to run my gunicorn instances and I was wondering if there is a default way to let a regular user run supervisorctl to start/stop the websites. I was thinking of adding some sudo config that would enable this user to run it but then I think it might open some loophole through which an intruder could run stuff as root. I know I can set user=someuser on the [supervisord] config section, but then I'd have to give permission to that user for files all over the filesystem, for logs, socket creation, etc. That would be a problem because the standard ubuntu package deploy assumes supervisor will be run as root.

So which one is better, or is there another alternative?

Answer (score 0):

sudo is really the better alternative here. If you are afraid that they can pass arguments to `supervisorctl` other than `start`/`stop`, maybe create two small binaries (not scripts!) that do nothing other than call `supervisorctl start`/`stop` (and not using `system(3)` but `exec(3)`) and only enable calling those two specific binaries for the user.

Comment: Surely a script will do. Just make sure that the user(s) in question can't write to the script ?

Comment: The problem with scripts is that they are insecure. Maybe not for such a simple script, but in time it will be modified. Because of this, I discourage their use.

Answer (score 0):

Deploy your websites in a buildout, build supervisor inside of it, and then bin/supervisorctl start/stop will be the user id, all the config will be in the buildout, and it will not require root.